# Set json file as environment variable

Tags: php, environment-variables, centos7, google-sheets-api

Please could I have step by step instructions to set the authentication.json file as environment variable instead of having the json file in my project location
For example:

```
$jsonAuth = getenv('JSON_AUTH');
```

Running CentOS Linux 7.9.2009 with Apache

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more detailed what you are trying to do and what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally,  you want to encode the json to base 64. Its easier as base64 gets rid of the printable characters that need to be escaped. After that, you can do the following in PHP.:

```
$jsonAuth = json_decode(base64_decode(getenv('JSON_AUTH')), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have [mod_env](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html) installed (it usually is, but double
   check this).
2. Find the `<VirtualHost>` for your application, and add `SetEnv JSON_AUTH your_token_here`, and as many other auth variables you
   need to set.
3. Reload Apache (`apachectl -k graceful` or via init.d).
4. Read out the variables using `$jsonAuth = apache_getenv('JSON_AUTH');`.

Comment: Keep in mind the option of just setting the whole JSON string as an environment variable, and reading it out with something like `json_decode(apache_getenv('JSON_AUTH'));` in your application. Depending on how complicated or large that string gets, this may be easier than separately setting a `SetEnv` for each variable from the credentials. This is entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks. When you say find <VirtualHost> - are you referring to editing my Apache config file? and adding SetEnv JSON_AUTH your_token_here to the config file between <VirtualHost></VirtualHost>? "your_token_here " - does that refer to my JSON object?

Comment: Exactly. `your_token_here` was just an example placeholder. You could insert the entire JSON in there. Just make sure that you're properly escaping everything. I'm not a big fan of base64-encoding everything as suggested by others, because this makes debugging and versioning a lot harder. Also, you wouldn't be learning anything by dodging the work ;).